# In an excel data of 3500 rows, How do I cut alternate row?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

In an excel data of 3500 rows, How do I cut alternate row and paste it else where? Recently, I have converted an pdf file in to excel file. I want to cut the alternate row and paste it infront of the original left rows? How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper column and enter the numbers 1,2,1,2,1,2 etc into that column. Then you can sort by that column, so all rows with 1 come first and all rows with 2 come after the rows with 1. After that, you can delete the helper column.